# Add JSON results to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have this JSON file with Currency Rates:

```
http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json
```

Can someone help me with a jQuery script so the results will look like:

`<div class="currency">USD</div><div class="value">1.000</div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null,function(data) {

       // ADD CODE HERE

    });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to loop through all of those rates.... you'll want to do something around the lines of this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   $(document).ready(function() { 
    var url =  "http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json"; 
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null,function(data) { 
       var myElementToAppendTo = $("#myElement");  // Note: add whatever element you are putting this into here
       $.each(data.rates, function(key, value) {
         if(key == "EUR" || key == "USD" || key == "GBP") {
           myElementToAppendTo.append("<div class='currency'>" + key + "</div><div class='value'>" + value + "</div>");
         }
       }

    }); 
   }); 


</script>
```

Comment: If I want to publish only EUR, USD and GBP for example, how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Look at @Jose Vega's response and modify for the ones you want or use the updated code I provided. I would recommend his as it'll be faster you won't have to loop through everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
<div class="currency">USD</div><div class="value"></div>
```

This code will get the value of the USD inside the div with class value.

```
$('div.value').text(data.rates.USD);
```

If what you want is to create a table with all the rates, you will have to loop over the rates index.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null,function(data) {
         jQuery.each(data, function(currency, value) {
         $("body").append("<div class="currency">"+currency+"</div><div class="value">"+value+"</div>");
          });

    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data.rates,function(key,val){
  var Div1 = $('<div class="currency" />').text(key).appendTo($('YOURFORM'));
  var Div2 = $('<div class="value" />').text(val).appendTo($('YOURFORM'));
});
```

something like that?